# Insert commas into string number

Tags: string, actionscript-3, flash, numbers

I have this code, and I want to put commas.

I've seen many examples, but I dont now were put the code.

This is my AS3 code:

```
calccn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,result1);

function result1(e:MouseEvent)
{

var vev: Number = (Number(vev.text));
var cn1: Number = (Number(3/100));

var result1f: Number = (Number(vev*cn1));
var round;
round=result1f.toFixed(0);
v3.text = String(round);
}
```

Example
If the result give me 1528000,32
I want that the result is 1.528.000 or 1 528 000

Comment: Please read this to understand why posting the image of code is not a good idea: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question then consider **editing** your question to improve it and make it easier for people to help you.

Comment: Use the [edit option](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71085841/edit) to paste your code as **text** (we will fix the formatting later). A picture cannot be tested in a programming tool. Where is your code for commas? Show it and we will tell you where to put it.

Comment: **PS:** What is an example of your number that needs commas? It's not obvious why you need commas (and not for example: decimal points, or parenthesis, or whatever). Ask a question like: `My code gives a number like 12999345. I want to add commas so it looks like 12,999,345. This is what I tried, how to improve it or where to put the tried code?` Then you'll get a faster Answer.

Comment: Thank you VC.One and Organis, I´m a rookie in flash, I´ve already edit my question, I think now is more compreensive question.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't know (*live and learn, eh*), but there's actually a dedicated class: [NumberFormatter](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/globalization/NumberFormatter.html).

If you want to do the thing on a regular basis, you might want a method to call:

```
// Implementation.
import flash.globalization.NumberFormatter;

// The default separator is comma.
function formattedNumber(value:Number, separator:String = ","):String
{
    var NF:NumberFormatter;
    
    NF = new NumberFormatter("en_US");
    
    // Enforce the use of the given separator.
    NF.groupingSeparator = separator;
    
    // Ignore the fraction part.
    NF.fractionalDigits = 0;
    
    return NF.formatNumber(value);
}

// Usage.

//Format the given number with spaces for separator.
trace(formattedNumber(1528000.32, " ")); // 1 528 000

//Format the given number with the default separator.
trace(formattedNumber(1528000.32)); // 1,528,000
```

But if you want just a simple one-timer, and don't really care if it is commas or spaces as long as they present you may just condense in into a single expression:

```
calccn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, result1);

function result1(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    // Declaring variables with the same names as
    // other entities is a generally bad idea.
    var input:Number = Number(vev.text);
    var cn1:Number = 3.0 / 100.0;
    
    // Keep in mind that I used int() here as
    // a simple tool to remove the fraction part. 
    v3.text = (new NumberFormatter("en_US")).formatNumber(int(input * cn1));
}
```